# How to winzip a folder exclude parent folders?

Tags: parent, directory, winzip

I am using this command to winzip a folder, but "bldforge_AOMS_DEV\WebSphere_AVOB" is included in the zip. 
winzip32.exe -min -a -r -p C:\Build\AOM.zip m:\bldforge_AOMS_DEV\WebSphere_AVOB*

How can I create the zip without "bldforge_AOMS_DEV\WebSphere_AVOB", just all the files under bldforge_AOMS_DEV\WebSphere_AVOB\?

Thanks
Jirong

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert by i think this might solve you problem

```
winzip32.exe -min -a -r -p C:\Build\AOM.zip m:\bldforge_AOMS_DEV\WebSphere_AVOB\*
```

just add a slash before your * selector